# What's difference between 受到 and 受？

Tags: meaning, difference

I find it very difficult to understand the difference between them . For example in this sentence: 网上购物能够受到人们的喜爱。

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the two is "**tense**".

**受 -** to receive/get/obtain.

**受到 -** have/has received/gotten/obtained.

Note that **到** is used as a verbal complement to indicate the (successful) completion of an action.

- 网上购物**受到**人们的喜爱。- Online shopping **has gotten** people's love.
- 网上购物受人们的喜爱。- Online shopping **gets** people's love.

Another example:

- 他佷**受到**(人们的/大家的)尊重 - He has received broad respect (from the people).
- 他佷**受**(人们的/大家的)尊重 - He receives broad respect (from the people).

Comment: “他很受到尊重” is not natural and idiomatic enough. If you want to use 受到+尊重， a word before 尊重 （e.g. 他受到大家的尊重, without 很）is more natural.

Comment: @Havier No objection here. Add 大家的 is a more complete sentence.

Comment: perhaps this answer could do with a little edit along the lines suggested by Havier?

Comment: @goPlayerJuggler Suggestion accepted.

Answer (score 1):

受 is a standalone verb and able to express more meaning by compounding other word (e.g. 受到， 承受，遭受，接受).
In your sentence "网上购物能够受到人们的喜爱。", You can use 受 here to express "to receive" (网上购物能够受人们的喜爱) and it also makes sense. Most people use "受到" instead of "受" to express "to receive" just because "受到" is more narrowly defined.